How does attributes and class variables of a particular class initialize when instantiated in another class?
Learning Data structures from freecodecamp.
Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hly31xKli0&t=10115s
While implementing the Linked list...
Focus on the size() and search() methods that are defined under LinkedList class in the code below.
We are declaring a pointer "current" assigning it to self.head attribute (current = self.head).
Then we observe "current.next_node". "next_node" is a class variable of class "Node". We instantiate the "Node" class under add() method and we use "next_node" with the object which completely makes sense since "Node" is instantiated under add() method.
But how come we are able to use the "next_node" variable inside size() and search() methods where "Node" class is not instantiated? What is the implication? We can use the attributes of a class under different class methods just by instantiating once in a method?
Please let me know what's happening...
class Node:
    data = None #Contains Node data
    next_node = None    #Contains reference to next node

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data    

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node data: {0}>".format(str(self.data))

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next_node = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def size(self):
        count = 0
        current = self.head
        print(current)

        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next_node
            print(current)

        return count

    def search(self,key):
       
        current = self.head     
        while current:
            if current.data == key:
                return current
            
            else:
                current = current.next_node
                print(current) 

        return None


    def __repr__(self):
        nodes = []
        current = self.head

        while current:
            nodes.append(str(current.data))
            current = current.next_node

        return "->".join(nodes)


Every node in the linked list was instantiated by add where the next_node attribute of the node object was also set. The attribute now belongs to the object. If you then get one of these node objects in another method, you can access its next_node attribute.

You can use attributes/methods of an object anywhere. Note, everything is an object. 1 is an object, the fact that you can do x = 1 + whatever inside of a method in your class is the exact same phenomenon

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

inside search() and size() you use self.head which can be None or it can be already instantiated Node (if you run search after add() which runs self.head = new_node = Node(data)) - so you work with instantiated Node and you can use next_node. And if it None then while current skips all code and it doesn't run next_node

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
